# What happens if two users try to update a document almost simultaneously in firestore?

Tags: database, concurrency, google-cloud-firestore

In update operation of firestore does it first download whole document and then after editing it uploads it back? does it queues transactions and processes them one by one or executes them at same time? 
Or its even more advanced the updates/changes to document happens absolute realtime?

Answer (score 0):

Update operations do not download the entire document first.

Transactions are performed atomically on selected documents.  You should [read the documentation on transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to understand how they work.

I don't understand your third question.

When multiple clients update a document without a transaction, the last write will overwrite the first write if there is a collision on the fields they update.